# How to call apscheduler decorator only when new updates comes in database

Tags: python, mongodb, apscheduler

In my code i need to add scheduler which calls every 30 sec when database has new updates.How to build that logic

Comment: Hi, what have you tried so far? Can you show your code?

Comment: Thanks. Actually I have to write that for the telegram bot to wait function till new updates comes in it and throws message after 30 sec if it has any updates.

Comment: Maybe you can use `time()`

Comment: how time() ...? means time.sleep() is it. I am confused to call update which is coming to database ,means how can i get to know that database has new value in it.